# python3: how can I paste code directly into console that calls a function instead of having to load a .py file?

Tags: python-3.x, console

In a python3 console I just want to copy and paste code directly into the console without loading a .py file but I get an error, probably because it's executing only one line at a time?

```
>>> def k():
... print("Hi")
... k()
File "<stdin>", line 3
k()
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

How can I run multi-line python code by just copying and pasting what I've written, into console instead of loading a .py file? I realize people will say it's stupid to do this, but hypothetically if it weren't stupid to do this, what's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this:

you have to paste the `def k():` after the prompt `>>>`  then paste your function code one line at a time after `...`  (with indents) then at the end of your function definition add an empty line (no indent) then you will get the `>>>`  prompt again where you paste your function call `k()` .

this was what I got

```
>>> def k():
...     print("hi")
...
>>> k()
hi
>>>
```